# Why is RLIMIT_NOFILE rlim_max of -1 on BSD?

Tags: macos, bsd, setrlimit

In the following code:

```
139     struct rlimit limit;
140 
141     method = "rlimit";
142     if (getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &limit) < 0) {
143       perror("calling getrlimit");
144       exit(1);
145     }
146 
147     /* set the current to the maximum or specified value */
148     if (max_desired_fds)
149       limit.rlim_cur = max_desired_fds;
150     else {
151         limit.rlim_cur = limit.rlim_max;
152     }
153 
154     if (setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &limit) < 0) {
155       perror("calling setrlimit");
156       exit(1);
157     }
```

the setrlimit line fails (I get the error "calling setrlimit"). Further investigation shows that `limit.rlim_max` is -1, which is not a valid value. Any ideas why would this be? This is on Mac OSX.

Answer (score 1):

If `setrlimit` fails, try again with `rlim_cur` set to `OPEN_MAX`.  For example, see http://source.winehq.org/source/libs/wine/loader.c#L653.  (The comment mentioning Leopard means that Leopard first introduced that behavior.  Read it as Leopard-and-later.)

ETA: See the note in COMPATIBILITY in the [setrlimit(2) man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/setrlimit.2.html).